# IndexOutOfBoundsException setSpan (0 ... 1) ends beyond length 0

Tags: android, android-edittext, indexoutofboundsexception, textwatcher

I am using this library for material editText with label:
https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/Text-Field
nice library :)

but...

i am using next code to check are entered symbols correct:

```
private boolean hasCorrectSymbols(String input){
        String tre = "[A-Za-z0-9\\@\\#\\$\\%\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\+\\_\\;\\:\\?\\.\\,\\!]+$";
        if (input.matches(tre)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

for checking correct symbols I am using textWatcher:

```
mEditPass.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() == 1 && !loginPassHasCorrectSymbols(s.toString())){
                    mEditPass.getText().clear();
                    String mess = getString(R.string.toast_login_useLatin);
                    showToastMessage(mess);
                } else if (s.length() >1 && !loginPassHasCorrectSymbols(s.toString())) {
                    String mess = getString(R.string.toast_login_useLatin);
                    showToastMessage(mess);
                    String text = s.toString();
                    text = text.substring(0, start);
                    mEditPass.setText(text);
                    mEditPass.setSelection(start);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });
```

if first symbol is correct and the second one for example is wrong - system will cut last entered (wrong) symbol and set cursor to the last text position, but if the first symbol is prohibited symbol - it will crash with this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (0 ... 1) ends beyond length 0
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1016)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:592)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
            at android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod.onTextChanged(PasswordTransformationMethod.java:108)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
            at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:683)
            at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:198)
            at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:183)
            at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
            at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas why it happen? And how to fix this??

Answer (score 6):

In this code snippet, you shorten the text displayed in the `EditText` (so that the last valid position is `start-1`), but still try to set the selection position to `start`.

```java
text = text.substring(0, start);
mEditPass.setText(text);
mEditPass.setSelection(start);
```

[EDITED]

Assuming that your Toast message is prompting the user to fix the error, I think what you actually want to do is to set the selection to the first character in the EditText with a bad symbol. Here is sample code for doing that:

```
// A reusable Pattern (at the class level) that defines the regex for bad characters.
private static final Pattern ILLEGAL_CHAR_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
    "[^A-Za-z0-9\\@\\#\\$\\%\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\+\\_\\;\\:\\?\\.\\,\\!]"
);

    // Replacement for your listener code.
    mEditPass.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() == 0 || count == 0) {
                return;
            }
            Matcher matcher = ILLEGAL_CHAR_PATTERN.matcher(s);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                int firstIllegalPos = matcher.start();
                mEditPass.setSelection(firstIllegalPos);
                String mess = getString(R.string.toast_login_useLatin);
                showToastMessage(mess);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: nope, it crashed when the first symbol is wrong, and it crash here:
mEditPass.getText().clear();
                    String mess = getString(R.string.toast_login_useLatin);
                    showToastMessage(mess);

Comment: The stack trace shows that the exception happened when the system was handling a message. Your code was not on the stack at all when the crash happened.

Comment: You need to determine which characters in `s` are "incorrect", remove them, and then determine what character you want to select (if any).

Comment: hm, it looks the same I am trying to do...
the first symbol is wrong, so i try to clear mEdit.pass....

Comment: Please see my edited answer. It looks like your Toast message is asking the user to fix the string, so my proposed code sets the selection to the first bad symbol. The text is not changed at all.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was fixed by adding next code:

```
mEditPass.getText().clearSpans();
```

before

```
mEditPass.getText().clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Error says you are ending the spanable text before its start, look for any character that you gave to end and its appearing before start

Answer (score 1):

you should trim the text.

```
spannable.setSpan(
            ForegroundColorSpan(textColor),
            FIRST_INDEX, someText.trim().length,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

Answer (score 0):

just add one more space to your string and then

```
mEditPass.setSelection(new string);
```